# MVC3: Make div as ajax.actionlink

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

So i have this actionlink which will trigger action "gotoContent" which will return a partialVIew into some div in current page

```
<div id="itemColumn">
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Go to content", "GotoContent", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "content" }, new { id = "item" })
</div>
```

So the problem is, this only triggered when we clicked right in the "Go to content" words, but what i need is, we can click everywhere on the whole div. It would be nice if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Try my posted solution and let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I decided I did not like the first answer I posted. Check out the newest answer that I have just posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make div containing ajax actionLink clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314116/make-div-containing-ajax-actionlink-clickable)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are asking I think the right and easiest way to do it would be something like this:

HTML:

```
 <div id="itemColumn">
  // put whatever text you want the Div to Contain but don't make it an action link. We will handle this in Jquery by essentially making your div an action link.
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
   $('#itemColumn').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("GotoContent", "ControllerName")',
             type: "GET",
             success: function(result) {
                $('#content').html(result);   // this will update your target div with the result (your partial view)
             }
       })
    })
});
```